# Ignore properties if not present in JSON request

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have a DTO that is used in my API function and maps using `[FromBody]`:

```
public class ExampleDto
{
  public int? PropertyA { get; init; }

  public string PropertyB { get; init; }
}

public ... Update([FromBody] ExampleDto dto, ...)
{
}
```

If `PropertyA` is omitted from the `JSON` request body, it is still seen as `null` in the `dto` but I want to allow actual `null` values to be provided in order to perform some logic.

So how do/can I differentiate between an explicit `null` value and that of the property being omitted from the request?

So for clarity:

```
{
  "propertyB": "Some value"
}
```

`PropertyA` has been omitted from the request, therefore perform no logic using that property. However, mapping from the request to the DTO results in that property still having a `null` value.

```
{
  "propertyA": null,
  "propertyB": "Some value"
}
```

`PropertyA` has been provided as `null` signalling that the value in the database should be set to `null`.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Both cases are `null`.  Not sure what kind of logic you want to implement around someone providing `null` as the value versus not providing a value at all (which would still be... `null`).

Comment: @TimothyG. The property is nullable in a database, so ideally want to know when an explicit null value is provided rather than the property being omitted so that I know for sure the user wants the value nulled.

Comment: You can use custom parser, check if property exists in json and mark this in property which is not serilized (fx ... `internal bool PropertyAExists {get;set;}`  that's it

Comment: ...but with this solution there would be the problem on the client side, too ... so another type (as in deleted comment) would be better i think

Comment: Do I get this right, that you kind of want to do this : Value exists => write Value to DB, Value exists but is null => Write DBNull to DB, Value is omitted => do not change whatever value is in DB?

Comment: @Selvin ah, sorry. Deleted because I thought it was a silly idea on second thought.

Comment: Nah ... I think that OP means exactly what you write in the comment and solution to have a speciall type for this is a good idea

Comment: Answers might be different if you are using NewtonSoft.JSON or System.Text.Json. Can you disclose, which one is preferred?

Comment: With my solution on client side you have to have the `XExists` also for proper serialization

Comment: This isn't a direct answer but I understand what you're getting at. In situations like this when I want to indicate the existing value should be nulled out (as opposed to just left alone) I use a special value to indicate this. For example -1 or int.MinValue could be used to indicate delete for an int. Something like "(null)" could be used for a string. Obviously you would need to document this well for your consumers and/or future you. :)

Comment: @Fildor You have the right idea.

Comment: Instead of using auto-properties, can you write an implementation that checks whether the property was set or not?

Comment: The other thing to think about is how this scales and cooperates with whatever database framework is being used. Custom attributes and JSON deserializers are great but how is that all going to get honored by the db framework?

Comment: @RubenHart is it an option for you to have all your DTOs inherit from a common base class? If so I think I have an idea that would not involve custom deserializers or attributes.

Comment: @JustAnswertheQuestion Yes, that could be an option as there are other DTOs that have a similar requirement.

Comment: I just realized this is the first time I've ever thought C# would benefit from having a `null` vs. `undefined` like JS/TS.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is if you write your own custom Json Deserializer by inheriting JsonConverter and implementing your own.  In this case, you'd be able to see the property name you are parsing out and then you could set what property names existed either as another property setter or maybe just as a List of strings or something on the target class.  Then you'd be able to make that distinction.

Answer (score 0):

You could decorate your class with JsonConverter attribute, which will take care of your special deserialization logic:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(ExampleDtoConverter))]
public class ExampleDto
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int? PropertyA { get; init; }

    public string PropertyB { get; init; }
}
```

Where JsonConverter would look something like this:

```
internal class ExampleDtoConverter : JsonConverter<ExampleDto>
{
    public override ExampleDto Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (typeToConvert != typeof(ExampleDto))
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException($"Unsupported type: {typeToConvert.Name}.");
        }
        JsonElement jsonObject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(ref reader, options);
        // is propertyA in JSON?
        if(jsonObject.TryGetProperty("PropertyA", out JsonElement propertyA))
        {
            // property exists and value is null?
            var value = propertyA.GetString();
            if(value is null)
            {
                // perform some special logic
            }
        }
        return new ExampleDto()
        {
            PropertyB = jsonObject.GetProperty("PropertyB").GetString() ?? string.Empty
            // Set PropertyB according to special logic
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the OP indicated a common base class could be used for all DTOs (which is a great practice anyway), here's a solution that would not require a custom deserializer and would make the database-update logic simple.

```
public class DTOBase
{
    Dictionary<string, object> _values = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    protected T GetValue<T>([CallerMemberName] string? key = null)
    {
        if (_values.TryGetValue(key, out var val) && val is T tval)
            return tval;
        return default;
    }

    protected void SetValue<T>(T val, [CallerMemberName] string key = null)
    {
        _values[key] = val;
    }

    public void Update(DTOBase updater)
    {
        foreach (var pair in updater._values)
        {
            this._values[pair.Key] = pair.Value; 
        }
    }
}
```

This takes advantage of the fact that the JSON deserializer by default will not invoke a property setter if the property is not present in the JSON string, but WILL if it's null or default (unless you change this behavior through decorators or custom deserialization settings - so don't).

The `Update` method would let you take an existing database record and, providing the update/request object, assign only those values which have been explicitly set through JSON.

So to use your example, your DTO would become:

```
public class ExampleDto : DTOBase
{
    public int? PropertyA
    {
        get => GetValue<int?>();
        set => SetValue(value);
    }

    public string PropertyB
    {
        get => GetValue<string>();
        set => SetValue(value);
    }
}
```

Here's some code to test this using either JSON.NET or System.Text.JSON:

```
        string omitted = @"
        {
            ""PropertyA"": 5
        }";

        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExampleDto>(omitted);
        var obj2 = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ExampleDto>(omitted);

        string notOmitted = @"
        {
            ""PropertyA"": 5,
            ""PropertyB"": null
        }";

        var obj3 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExampleDto>(notOmitted);
        var obj4 = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ExampleDto>(notOmitted);
```

If you debug you'll see the latter two objects have two members in their `_values` dictionaries whereas the first two only have one.

In your actual API, you would then -

- Pull the entire existing record from the database
- Call `Update` with the body parameter
- Insert/Update the record back into the database

Alternatively in the unlikely event you're constructing your own `UPDATE` statements you could extend `DTOBase` to access the `_values` dictionary to form the basis for your updates.

The only downside is the need to refactor all your DTO property getters and setters, but remember this abstraction not only gets you the information you need as far as what was actually specified in the JSON object vs. not, but also makes using that information in your database update process quite easy and scalable.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class ExampleDto
{
    public int? PropertyA { get; set; }
    public string PropertyB { get; set; }
}

var dto = new ExampleDto { PropertyA = null, PropertyB = "example" };
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dto, settings);
```

OR

Using attribute like this:

```
public class ExampleDto
{
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public int? PropertyA { get; init; }

    public string PropertyB { get; init; }
}
```

Comment: This obviously doesn't answer the question ... OP wana make distinction between `{ "PropertyA" : null }` and `{ }` ... With your code there would be such, as in both cases `PropertyA` would be `null`